# Is there support for 2.3 for loaders in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-3.0-honeycomb

I know that Loaders are introduced in Android 3.0, but is there support for 2.3 like the support for Fragments ? Fragments are also for 3.0 but with the support API you can use them in earlier version I think back to 1.6

Comment: I found it in the documentation it says " Most importantly, the library provides implementations of the Fragment and Loader APIs...."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep loaders are also in the compatibility library!

Comment: Can you give some link where I can read little more about this ?, I was sniffing in android skd but I didn't menages to find something useful I guess that is because I didn't know how to find it...

Comment: @user706780 unfortunately its all undocumented, you need to go into the android SDK manager, click on available packages and under the android repository is the Android compatibility package. Get that, include the jar into your project and off ya go. If you get stuck let me know I will try to help.